# Bind ListView with list of Interfaces instead of classes

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, interface

Ok, this is a little complicated, so let me explain.

I have several classes in an existing project that have different contact information. For example, CompanyContact may contain

```
 1. CompanyName
 2. Phone
 3. Fax
```

ProviderContact may have

```
1. ProviderName
2. FirstName, 
3. LastName, 
4. Phone, 
5. Fax
```

and ProviderLocation may have

```
1. Name (location name)
2. Phone1
3. Fax1
```

Each class has additional properties, this is just a subset.  Some of the fields mean the same thing, but are named different.  CompanyName,ProviderName, and Name (in ProviderLocation) all mean the same thing, just as Phone and Phone1 are the same (at least for my purposes).

I created an interface IFaxContact to try to provide a common interface to all of these classes because I need to get contact info from them in different circumstances for automating faxing and email.

```
public interface IFaxContact
{
    string EntityName { get; set;}
    string FullName {get; set;}
    string Email { get; set;}
    string Fax { get; set;}
    string Phone { get; set;}
}
```

I explicitly implemented this in all of the classes in question, but if the property already exists, I did not add it again as the existing property would serve for all implementations.

I currently have a factory class that is creating the individual classes and returning objects of IFaxContact or `List<IFaxContact>` . This is working well for the most part.

Now, I have a ListView control where I am binding a `List<IFaxContact>` as the datasource. When it does the binding, it is referring to the object as the base class (i.e. CompanyContact) instead of the interface IFaxContact, and is giving me errors because the field does not exist.  I tried to cast it in the binding expression to IFaxContact, but its not taking it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvRecipients" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lvRecipients_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></li>
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>**<span style="width: 100px; margin-right: 2px;"><%# Eval("FullName") %></span>
            <span style="width: 100px; margin-right: 2px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval((Entities.IFaxContact)Container.DataItem, "EntityName")%></span>
            <span style="width: 50px; margin-right: 2px;"><%# Eval("Fax") %></span>
            <span style="width: 50px;">**
             <a href="#" runat="server" onclick="lnkAddOtherRecipient_Click">
               <i class="fa faGreen fa-plus fa-lg "></i>
             </a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The binding is being done in the ItemTemplate above.

The errors I get are like:
    System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'Entities.CompanyContact' does not contain a property with the name 'EntityName'.

This is because EntityName exists under IFaxContact, and not in the classes (i.e. CompanyContact), but the DataItem is of type CompanyContact (or one of the other classes).

I need some help in figuring out either how to properly cast the Container.DataItem in the Eval(...) expression to IFaxContact, or another solution that will work with the interface as I currently have it designed.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Eval like this: `<%# Eval("ProviderContact.ProviderName") %>`

Comment: well that kind of defeats the purpose in using an interface. Its not always going to be a ProviderContact.

Comment: My solution was to copy the list to a list of anonymous objects, then bind the control to that list. It will be a short list (< 15 items) so I am not worried about performance at this time.